# Migrate Windows Dynamic disk RAID5 to Linux LVM

Tags: raid, migration, raid5

Is this even possible, do I have the right tool in mind?
I have 3 disks that are running as a software RAID5  using windows.  I would like to migrate box to Linux without experiencing  data loss.
Am I dreaming?

Thanks,
Devan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to keep the data in-place? Then yes, you're dreaming.

If you have 3 separate disks of equal or greater capacity, you could create LVM PV's and LVs on the new disks and copy the data over from the old disks, but that's about it.

Comment: Stupid followup, how would I mount the old disks to copy to the new?

Comment: @user1440598 - not stupid at all; I forgot that Windows RAID5 disks are dynamic, which means you're basically screwed. You will need to mount them in a different computer, or backup, format, restore.

Comment: Backup, Format, Restore is probably the safest path. If for no other reason than if/when things go all pear-shaped you have a ***BACKUP*** :-)